# How to make a competition input form and a view?

Tags: forms, rules

I want to put scores in a form. See screenprint:

[image]

Some details about it:

- 2 pulldown menu's with players.
- 2 text boxes for the score, example: (8) and (2).

In the above example, the automatically calculated "comp score" will be `3` and `1`. If however the score is (6) and (6), then the comp score will be `1,5` and `1,5`.

So to summarize (about how to calculate the "comp score":

- When the score is equal both players get `1,5`.
- The winner gets `3`, the loser gets `1`.

They play in poules, several matches. Each match is put in like in the screenprint above.

The scores will be added up. And in a view they will be shown on the site as a ranking. The best on top.

I don't know how to imput the data, automatically give the comp score and how to add them up (to make the view will go).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid writing a manual (to answer your question), here is a blueprint ...

#### Content type Game

Create a content type "game", with 2 entity ref fields to another content type like "player", and the other fields like date, etc.

#### 3 Rules Components

Create 3 similar rules components (with parameters the score for player 1, and another parameter for score of player 2):

- a 1st Rules Component with a Rules Condition to check if player1 has won, in which case you perform a 1st Rules Action to "set a data value" to set the "comp score" for player 1, and a similar 2nd Rules to set the "comp scrore" for player 2. Then add an extra Rules Action to save the entity (to ensure the comp value is also saved).
- a (similar) 2nd Rules Component to check if player2 has won.
- a 3rd , and one if the score was equal.

#### Custom rule

Create a custom rule like so:

- Rules Event: before saving content of type "game"
- Rules Actions: Perform 3 Actions, whereas each of these action performs one of the Rules Components create as described above.

#### Create a view games

Create a view of all your games. In doing so, use the [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) module to "add up the scores".

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.